# HDMI input not recognized on ASUS N76

Tags: 12.10, display, asus, hdmi

I have a brand new ASUS N76 with newly installed 12.10.
HDMI port is not recognized by Ubuntu while working perfectly well with Windows 8.
xrandr does not even show as known connector :

Output of  `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 382mm x 215mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
[...]
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Are you using native binary drivers or the open source ones included in Ubuntu?

Comment: i have installed Bumblebee because of optimus features of nvidia GT650M on board. Everything else should be native.

Comment: not much help there ...

Comment: hummm .. Allo !?? ...

Comment: nobody there ? huh ?

Answer (score 1):

Asus N76 has connected HDMI via nVidia graphic chip. See bumblebee multi-monitor setup: https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Multi-monitor-setup

After you configure bumblebee (change bumblebee nvidia xorg.conf conf file and restart), you can run application on HDMI screen using:

```
export DISPLAY=:8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
optirun some-command
```

I'm using this command to run another gnome sesstion:

```
optirun gnome-session --session=gnome-classic
```

You can also manage inputs using xinput comand. Connect external keyboard after an HDMI screen active and use commands

```
export DISPLAY=:0  // for internal display
export export DISPLAY=:8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH // for HDMI

xinput // find your device and it id, you can use xinput | grep "part of name"
xinput list-props <device id> | grep "Device Enabled"   // find enabled property state and (property id).
xinput set-prop <device id> <property id> <value> // to set value
```

This is my script which enable Lenovo devices on HDMI screen, if exists:

```
#!/bin/bash

# switch to main display to make sure, that Xserver is running and xinput will provide list of devices.
export DISPLAY=:0
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# find list of devices to work with. See `xintput` command output
DEVICES="`xinput | grep "Lenovo Multimedia Remote with Keyboard N5902" | sed -e 's/.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`"
echo $DEVICES

# switch to nVidia Xserver at DISPLAY 8
export DISPLAY=:8 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/nvidia-current:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

# Test xinput command. If it fail, enable DEVICES at main Xserver.
# Otherwise enable DEVICES at Xserver running on DISPLAY 8
xinput>/dev/null&>/dev/null 
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
{
    echo "HDMI Xserver is not running."
    MAIN_STATUS=1

} else {
    echo "HDMI Xserver is running."
    MAIN_STATUS=0

    for DEV in $DEVICES
    do
        PROP=`xinput list-props $DEV | grep "Device Enabled" | sed -e 's/.*(\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`
        echo "$DEV - $PROP"
        xinput set-prop $DEV $PROP 1
        xinput list-props $DEV | grep "Device Enabled"
    done
} fi

# switch back to DISPLAY 0 and update DEVICES status according to MAIN_STATUS.
export DISPLAY=:0
unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH

for DEV in $DEVICES
do
    PROP=`xinput list-props $DEV | grep "Device Enabled" | sed -e 's/.*(\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`
    xinput set-prop $DEV $PROP $MAIN_STATUS
    xinput list-props $DEV | grep "Device Enabled"
done
```

Here is another approach which use synergy server/client for key/mouse switchting. But it's too slow for gaming.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/get-hdmi-working-with-nvidia-optimus-on.html

Good luck.